# Anyone know what this yellow titlebar is, and how to remove it?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, monitoring, window-title, pop-os

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> (activities overview) got remapped to this and I can't seem to figure out how to change it back. This title bar shows up on the focused window when I hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, and then newly opened windows start to group together.

I'm on Pop!_OS 20.04 running Gnome 3.36.3.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I'd like to map <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> back to the activities overview, but this thing wont seem to let me.

Comment: I guess you're using Pop Shell for windows-tiling, you should look into the settings of the extension in GNOME Tweaks or GNOME Extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is actually a feature of Pop Shell for stacking windows, like Loic Reynier suggested in the comments, but you can't change it with GNOME Tweaks.

You can find the settings of Pop Shell shortcuts [here](https://github.com/pop-os/shell/blob/master_focal/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.pop-shell.gschema.xml), and change them with the following command.

```
dconf write '/org/gnome/shell/extensions/pop-shell/toggle-stacking-global' "['<Super><Shift>s']"
```

This changes the stacking shortcut to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>